# Getting extended properties on users objects

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I try to query a user including extended properties:

```
/users/xxx@xx.dk?$expand=properties
```

However I get following error:

> Could not find a property named 'properties' on type 'microsoft.graph.user.

Is it possible in one request to get a `user` object with all of it's extended properties?

Best scenario would be something like following where I query for the `departmentNumber` from the extended properties with direct properties:

```
/users/xx@xx.dk?$select=companyName,officeLocation,departmentNumber&$expand=properties
```

Comment: Extended properties are not a feature of [User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0). It is a feature of Mail, Event, and Contacts (I believe). I think you want to use a feature called [Schema Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/schemaextension?view=graph-rest-1.0). How is the departmentNumber being added to the User object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, as the message states, there *is* no property named `properties`.

How you retrieve custom properties depends on how they were created. There are two types: [Open Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-open-users) and [Schema Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-schema-groups). Each is stored and behaves a little differently so you'll want to refer to the documentation I linked to for help determining which type you want to use.

Comment: Got it working now: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xx@xx.dk?$select=companyName,officeLocation,departmentNumber,extension_xx_employeeNumber. The property just wasent synced. Thanks all!